# Weird undefined when create a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I instanced a new `object` with `new` keyword.`DigitalClock` and `AnalogClock` inheritance from base `Clock` class. After that I `console.log` `tick()` function from `childclass`. But console display `undefined` and result from `tick()`. What's wrong with me?

**clock.ts**

```
class Clock {
    h: number;
    m: number;

    constructor(h: number, m: number) {
        this.h = h;
        this.m = m;
    }
}

export class DigitalClock extends Clock {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) {
        super(h, m);
    }
    tick(): void {
        console.log(`beep beep at ${this.h}: ${this.m}`);
    }
}

export class AnalogClock extends Clock {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) {
        super(h, m);
    }
    tick(): void {
        console.log(`tick tock at ${this.h}:${this.m}`);
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import { DigitalClock, AnalogClock } from "./clock";

const digital = new DigitalClock(1, 23);
const analog = new AnalogClock(2, 31);

console.log(digital.tick());
console.log(analog.tick());
```

**result from console**

```
beep beep at 1: 23
undefined
tick tock at 2:31
undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
console.log(digital.tick());
```

First runs `digital.tick`, which calls

```
console.log(`beep beep at ${this.h}: ${this.m}`)
```

which already outputs to the console - that beep beep you wanted. But then the function returns to your original line, which attempts to send to the console the return value from `digital.tick`. As there is no such value, you get the `undefined` output. Just call the functions, no need to `console.log` them as well, since you already do that in the function:

```
digital.tick();
analog.tick();
```